# Exclude myself from friendship page - MySQL

Tags: mysql, fetch

This is my query to fetch user's friends. But there is a problem. If receiver is session user it is returning itself as friend.

```
SELECT user.name_surname, user.id, friendship.receiver_id, friendship.sender_id
FROM user
JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.receiver_id
WHERE 
    (friendship.receiver_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]." OR friendship.sender_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"].") 
     AND is_approved='1'"
```

Below table is my MySQL table design. I'am logged on as `user_id =16` to site. Then `user_id=19` sent me a frienship request. Then I approved it. Everything is beautiful up here but when I want to see my friends I also see myself as my friend.

How do I exlude myself at friends page?

[image: friendship table]

---

**attempted below**

If I change this line

```
JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.receiver_id
```

TO

```
JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.sender_id
```

this time another user who sent me friendship request sees his/her self as his/her friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user.name_surname, user.id, friendship.receiver_id, friendship.sender_id
FROM user
JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.sender_id OR user.id = friendship.receiver_id
WHERE (friendship.receiver_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]." OR friendship.sender_id  =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"].") 
AND is_approved='1'
AND user.id != ".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]."
```

Answer (score 0):

would

```
"AND user.id != " . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]
```

not do? So your whole query will be:

```
SELECT user.name_surname, user.id, friendship.receiver_id, friendship.sender_id
FROM user
JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.receiver_id
WHERE (friendship.receiver_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]." OR friendship.sender_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . ") 
AND is_approved='1'
AND user.id != " . $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]
```

Edit:
I think your query should be:

```
SELECT user.name_surname, user.id, friendship.receiver_id, friendship.sender_id
FROM user
JOIN friendship ON user.id = friendship.receiver_id
AND friendship.receiver_id != " . $_SESSION['SES_USER_ID'] . "
WHERE (friendship.receiver_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"]." OR friendship.sender_id =".$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] . ") 
AND is_approved='1'
```

Comment: if I add only this query it returns all users from user table!!

Comment: I know that also below answerer talked about it but it it returing noting. Actually I have 1 friend

Comment: you say "If receiver is session user it is returning itself as friend", have you tried `friendship.receiver_id != $_SESSION['SES_USER_ID']` Mr Cimbom'lu? :D

Comment: @hakiko I modified the query, try the second one.

Comment: no it is not working. Because user can receiver or sender when they stared friendship